# Почему переводчик Google переводит только первую строку текста?

Tags: delphi, google-translate

Делаю запрос на перевод текста из `Memo1.Text` в Google Переводчик и получаю результат перевода в `Memo2.Text`.

Почему переводится только первая строка `Memo1.Text`, а не весь текст что есть в `Memo1.Text`?

Вот полный, простой код:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Data: TStringList;
  s : String;
begin
  IdHTTP1.Request.UserAgent := 'Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16';
 
  Data := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Data.Text := ('client=x' + #13#10
                + 'text=' + Memo1.Text + #13#10
                + 'hl=ru' + #13#10
                + 'sl=ru' + #13#10
                + 'tl=en');
 
      s := IdHTTP1.Post('http://translate.google.ru/translate_a/t', Data);
 
    Memo2.Text := s;
  finally
    Data.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Может надо удалить символы перевода строки из первого мемо?

Comment: Скорее всего в запросе весь текст должен идти в одну строку после `text=`, все что переходит на другие строки не считается продолжением параметра `text`.

Comment: Не из кода надо убирать, а из первого мемо.

Comment: `'text=' + StringReplace(Memo1.Text, #13#10, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]) + #13#10`

Comment: @zed, Такой вариант то хороший но тогда после перевода теряется формат расположения строк текста. То есть если текст был в столбик в первом Memo1 то в Memo2 он уже в один ряд расположен. А нужно что бы также был переведен в столбик.

Comment: Без понятия. Можете попробовать вставлять не один пробел, а два. Если в переводе будет так же два пробела, то их потом можно будет заменить обратно на перевод строки. Но вероятно, должен быть более человеческий способ сохранять форматирование, используя API. Поищите в доках.

Comment: @zed, И на этом спасибо, такой вариант тоже пойдет. Сейчас попробую сделать так как Вы выше подсказали. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему переводится только первая строка Memo1.Text. А не весь текст что есть в Memo1.Text?

У вас в коде `Data.Text := …` видно, что параметры отделены друг от друга символами `#13#10`, что соответствует разделителю строк. Сервер встречает конец первой строки, и считает что параметр `text` закончился. Поэтому переводится только первая строка.

Что с этим можно сделать?

Я вижу минимум два варианта:

1. Отправлять каждую строку отдельно, и результат перевода поочередно добавлять в Memo2.
2. Убрать из текста пару символов `#13#10`. Можно как предлагали выше заменить на пробел. Можно попытаться найти документацию. Можно попытаться подобрать другой символ-разделитель. Велика вероятность, что разделителем должен быть одиночный символ `#10`